# PHP Namespace Syntax: What is the Difference with Braces vs. without Braces?

Tags: php, namespaces

PHP offers two syntax for declaring namespaces. You can use a namespace with no braces or with braces as seen below.

**Without Braces**

```
namespace foo/bar;
class Any{}
```

**With Braces**

```
namespace foo/bar {
   class Any{}
}
```

Is there a difference in the functionality or behavior of these two ways of using namespaces or do they both work/function the same way?

Comment: See [Defining multiple namespaces in the same file](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php)

Comment: Why close this, I wonder? It seems like a clear, useful, answerable question whose answer takes more than a cursory glance at the documentation to find. The [Namespaces Overview](http://php.net/manual/language.namespaces.rationale.php) and [Defining Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/language.namespaces.definition.php) pages don't even mention that the bracketed syntax *exists*, which leaves open the question of whether the several facts documented there apply to the bracketed syntax or only the unbracketed syntax. I have voted to reopen and encourage others to do the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are different reasons for each case, there is a [good example on the PHP site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php).

The reason you'd use curly brackets around a namespace is if there are multiple namespaces in the one file or where you need to have global non-namespaced code in the same file as code that is contained within a namespace.

Also if there are multiple namespaces in one file, the non-bracketed syntax is allowed as well.

As per php guidelines this is not recommended and if you can, just keep it to one namespace per file.

Comment: "if there are multiple namespaces in one file" => the non-bracketed syntax allows this as well.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>In the first variant, you can only use one namespace per file, whereas the second allows for multiple namespaces.</strike> They can be used interchangeably and may occur multiple times in a single file to define multiple namespaces. The only reason to use curly braces is in this case:

```
namespace {
    // code is in global scope
}
```

Other than the above example, a potential downside of having multiple namespaces in a single file is autoloaders that use the directory and file names to resolve classes to load; it's therefore not recommended to have more than one namespace per file, *unless* you're combining multiple script files into one.

Comment: "In the first variant, you can only use one namespace per file" => false.

Comment: Not true...see example 1 of [Defining multiple namespaces in the same file](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php)

Answer (score 0):

How is it possible to set global namespace without brackets?

```
<?php
declare(encoding='UTF-8');
namespace MyProject {

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }
}

namespace { // global code
session_start();
$a = MyProject\connect();
echo MyProject\Connection::start();
}
?>
```

just try to write this code in non-brackets style

Answer (score -2):

I think the first one only includes "Any" class. But the second one includes all classes between curly braces.

Comment: No, all classes in that file will be in that namespace